# Ionic: view-subtitle

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

In my angular-ionic application I would like to add a subtitle (similar to 'Alphabetic') below the view-title. Is this possible, or is there any workaround on the web?

[image]

Right now, my template looks like this:
(I've tried adding view-subtitle="test" next to view-title, but no luck so far)

```
<ion-view view-title="Problems">
  <ion-content>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see support for this in the docs, so I added an issue for it. See: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/2851

Comment: @Raymond Camden Found a 'solution', added it in the comment section of your github topic.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-view title="<div class='main-title' style='line-height: 1.6;'>Main Title</div><div class='sub-title' style='line-height: .6;font-size: 12px;color: #333;'>Sub Title</div>">

<ion-content>
...
</ion-content>

</ion-view>
```

[Output Image snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nk5hQ.png)

Answer (score -1):

There are quite a few ways to customize Headers.  A secondary header bar can also be placed below the original header bar using Ionic's CSS Sub Header component and this achieves a very similar look. http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#subheader

```
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark" align-title="center">
    <button class="button button-icon" ng-click="toggleCompanies()">
      <i class="icon ion-navicon"></i>
    </button>
    <h1 class="title large">Employees</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark bar-subheader">
    <div class="small">Alphabetic</div>
  </ion-header-bar>
```

Apply Some CSS style

```
.small {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

[image]

Plunker example here:  http://embed.plnkr.co/LOxXsc/preview